# What is a 平の家? Does 子ども refer to here? The chicks? Finally. .what does it mean to be とても はやかすの

Tags: translation

私が小学校へ入ったとき、近所のチャボのよいおん鳥をかりてきて、しばらくいっしょにおきました。ひよこができたとき、おん鳥もいっしょに「コッコッコッ」といいながら、えさをやります。**そのときの子どもはいま平の家にいます。平の家でもそのチャボはとてもはやかすのが上手だと喜んでいます。**

Comment: Assuming you have copied the text correctly, this whole paragraph looks broken and unorganized to me. Was this really written by a native Japanese speaker? Do you have the title of this work? Does the author speak in some dialect? For now, probably we can only give wild guesses, but knowing about the background of this work might help.

Comment: Hi Naruto, thanks for the response. It's from a book about Buddhism. The author quotes an essay in full that his niece wrote when she was 11 about her family's chicken.

Answer (score 1):

This is a poorly-written essay with several grammar errors. (It's awful for an average 11-year-old girl today, but this may have been written long ago when education level was lower.) It's not difficult to guess the rough meaning of each sentence, but some word usages are indeed puzzling even to native speakers today. I'm pretty certain about 子ども, but I may be wrong about 平の家 and はやかす.

- 子ども certainly refers to the ひよこ, or the [Chabo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_bantam)'s chicken.
- 平の家 is probably "Taira's house", i.e., the house owned by someone called 平. (Maybe the niece did not explain who 平 is?)
- はやかす is not a common verb, but I guess it's a variant of [囃す](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%9B%83%E3%81%99), which is like "to make sounds in a way they amuse/excite people". In some dialects はやかす is a variant of 生やす, but 生やす doesn't make sense here.

Here is my understanding of the sentences:

> そのときの子どもはいま平の家にいます。
>   The (Chabo's) child (I raised) at that time is now at Taira's house.
>
> 平の家でもそのチャボはとてもはやかすのが上手だと喜んでいます。
>   Also at Taira's house, people are delighted that the Chabo is very good at singing.